# Xamarin forms with Entity Framework Core and encrypted sqlite take too long

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, autofac, sqlcipher

When combining Xamarin forms with EF Core and SQLite no problem small delay but when using encryption there are too much delay

AppContext

```
public AppContext(string dbPath)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath)) 
        _dbPath = dbPath;

    SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();

    this.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

`OnConfiguring`:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    //optionsBuilder
    //    .UseSqlite($"Filename={dbPath}");

    connection = InitializeSQLiteConnection(_dbPath);

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
}

private static SqliteConnection InitializeSQLiteConnection(string databaseFile)
{
    var connectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
        DataSource = databaseFile,
        Password = "Test123"
    };
    return new SqliteConnection(connectionString.ToString());
}
```

The used Packages

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core
- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core
- SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher

For dependency injection I use AutoFac

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Store.db3");

builder.RegisterType<DataBase.Services.AppContext>().As<IDatabaseContext>().WithParameter("dbPath", "dbPath").InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: what is "too long"?  You have to expect that performing encryption on the fly is going to add some overhead to your db operations

Comment: Ok, at first opening connection, not for every action

Comment: @SherifAwad Using SQLCipher to encrypt may spend little as 5-15% overhead, affect permormance.

Answer (score 0):

The first use of a connection with SQLCipher is deliberately slow due to [key derivation](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-performance-optimization/14).